# Outer join in classic Oracle join syntax

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to convert my query to classic Oracle join syntax because I need to put it in a materialized view. However, I'm not quite sure how to do it:

```
SELECT * FROM transactions t
LEFT JOIN transac_detail td1 ON (t.id = t1.trans_id AND t.ttype = 'VOICE')
LEFT JOIN transac_detail td2 ON (t.id = t2.trans_id AND t.ttype = 'BROADBAND');
```

I started writing it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM transactions t, transac_detail td1, transac_detail td2
WHERE t.id = t1.trans_id(+) AND t.id = t2.trans_id(+)
```

But how can I include the "literal" conditions?

Comment: It seems unlikely to me that a materialized view would not accept the modern ISO join notation.  Are you quite sure it is necessary?  It seems like a very unexpected restriction - the sort of thing that would only be done if Oracle has no intention of supporting materialized views in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original query confused. do you mean this?

```
SELECT t.* FROM transactions t, transac_detail td1
WHERE t.id = td1.trans_id(+)
and t.ttype = 'VOICE'
union
SELECT t.* FROM transactions t, transac_detail td2
WHERE t.id = td2.trans_id(+)
and t.ttype = 'BROADBAND'
```

Comment: The original query has results from transactions and two sets of transac_detail; yours has from just one transac_detail - so the result is certainly not the same.  It might be acceptable, but I'm not sure that it should be given the question.